# What is the syntax for creating a queue subscriber in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, callback, queue

I'm trying to create a queue and a callback that triggers when a message is queued, but I can't get the callback to trigger.  What am I doing wrong?

I have a trigger that enqueues a message, and I can see it on the queue message table, and I can dequeue it by hand and process it, I just can't get the callback to fire on enqueue.

```
BEGIN    
DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
  queue_table        => 'queue_message_table',
  queue_payload_type => 'queue_message_type',
  multiple_consumers => TRUE);

DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
  queue_name  => 'message_queue',
  queue_table => 'queue_message_table');
DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (queue_name => 'message_queue');
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE queue_callback(
  context RAW, reginfo  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO, descr SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR, payload  RAW, payloadl NUMBER) AS

    queue_options       DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    message_properties  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
    my_message          queue_message_type;
    ret                 varchar2(200);
    message_id          RAW(16);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Callback');
    queue_options.msgid := descr.msg_id;
    queue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;

    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
        queue_name => descr.queue_name,
        dequeue_options => queue_options,
        message_properties => message_properties,
        payload => my_message,
        msgid => message_id );
    ret := handle_message(my_message);
    commit;
END;

BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER (queue_name => 'message_queue',
    subscriber => SYS.AQ$_AGENT('queue_subscriber', 'message_queue',NULL));
  DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
    SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
      SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
        'MESSAGE_QUEUE:QUEUE_SUBSCRIBER',
        DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
        'plsql://QUEUE_CALLBACK',
        HEXTORAW('FF')
      )
    ), 1
  );
END;
```

Comment: Have you fixed this? I'm having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502535/oracle-advance-queue-dequeue-not-working

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it appears you're neither starting the queue (`dbms_aqadm.start_queue`), neither are you enqueueing anything to it (`dbms_aq.enqueue`).

I'd recommend following this [demo](http://www.psoug.org/reference/aq_demo1.html).

Comment: There are definitely messages making it onto the queue, I can see them.  Something is wrong in the callback creation syntax.

Comment: I notice there is no reference to queue_callback in your calls to the AQ APIs.

Comment: There's a reference to it in the AQ.REGISTER call, it's in the REG_INFO constructor.  That seems to be how the online demos do it, but clearly I'm missing something.  Do you know where the reference to the callback goes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the database version. some bugs has been reported about [issues with Oracle Aq](http://bluefrog-oracle.blogspot.com/2011/10/plsql-aq-notification.html).
In particular I've followed [this link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=411) to built my own sample, executing the demo in a Oracle 11gR2 enterprise database. I was abled to enqueue, dequeue, purge the queue but the listener created with Dbms_Aq.Register didn't work.
I ran the same example downloading a Oracle 11g R2 xe database and it worked.

The same example was runned in a Oracle 10gR2 instance and it works perfectly.

There are some things that you need to be careful on using aq:

- use the appropriate parameters adding the subscriber
- use the appropriate namespace registering the listener with Dbms_Aq.Register
- use the multiple consumers flag declaring the queue table
- use the appropriate permissions to packages and to handle the queues
- use the qualified name of the queues in some cases if it didn't works.

'
First create the schema

```
connect / as sysdba
-- @?/rdbms/admin/dbmsaqad.sql --(install if you don't have aq installed yet)

-- create the user and permissions
create user aqadmin identified by aqadmin default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;
GRANT create session TO aqadmin;
grant connect, resource to aqadmin;
GRANT aq_administrator_role TO aqadmin IDENTIFIED BY aqadmin;
GRANT execute ON dbms_aq TO aqadmin;
GRANT execute ON dbms_aqadm TO aqadmin;
```

Create the ddl objects

```
CREATE TABLE demo_queue_message_table
( message VARCHAR2(4000) );
```

Create the aq-objects

```
create or replace type demo_queue_payload_type as object(message varchar2(4000)) ;
/

begin
  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => 'demo_queue_table', queue_payload_type => 'demo_queue_payload_type',multiple_consumers => TRUE);
  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (queue_name => 'demo_queue', queue_table => 'demo_queue_table');
  DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE('demo_queue');
end;
/

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE demo_queue_callback_procedure(
                 context  RAW,
                 reginfo  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
                 descr    SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
                 payload  RAW,
                 payloadl NUMBER
                 ) AS

   r_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   v_message_handle     RAW(16);
   o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;

BEGIN

   r_dequeue_options.msgid := descr.msg_id;
   r_dequeue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;

   DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
      queue_name         => descr.queue_name,
      dequeue_options    => r_dequeue_options,
      message_properties => r_message_properties,
      payload            => o_payload,
      msgid              => v_message_handle
      );

   INSERT INTO demo_queue_message_table ( message )
   VALUES ( 'Message [' || o_payload.message || '] ' ||
            'dequeued at [' || TO_CHAR( SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                        'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) || ']' );
   COMMIT;

END;
/


BEGIN

   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER (
      queue_name => 'demo_queue',
      subscriber => SYS.AQ$_AGENT(
                       'demo_queue_subscriber',
                       NULL,
                       NULL )
      );

    DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
       SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
          SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
             'DEMO_QUEUE:DEMO_QUEUE_SUBSCRIBER',
             DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
             'plsql://DEMO_QUEUE_CALLBACK_PROCEDURE',
             HEXTORAW('FF')
             )
          ),
       1
       );
END;
/
```

And finally test the queue

```
DECLARE

   r_enqueue_options    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   v_message_handle     RAW(16);
   o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;

BEGIN

   o_payload := demo_queue_payload_type(
                   TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3' )
                   );

   DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(
      queue_name         => 'demo_queue',
      enqueue_options    => r_enqueue_options,
      message_properties => r_message_properties,
      payload            => o_payload,
      msgid              => v_message_handle
      );

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```