# Registered subscriber not getting messages from queue

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

We have a process using Oracle AQ on Oracle 11.2.  It was working just fine, buy yesterday, messages in the queue stopped getting dispatched to the subscriber.  Here is the setup we have to create the queue and register the handler.

```
 DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
          queue_table        => 'mdms_queue_table',
          queue_payload_type => 'U$_MDM_QUEUE_OBJECT',
          multiple_consumers => TRUE
          );

         DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
          queue_name  => 'mdms_queue',
          queue_table => 'mdms_queue_table'
          );

       DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (
          queue_name => 'mdms_queue'
          );

       DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER (
          queue_name => 'mdms_queue',
          subscriber => SYS.AQ$_AGENT(
                           'mdms_queue_subscriber',
                           NULL,
                           NULL )
          );

       DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
          SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
             SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
                'mdms_queue:mdms_queue_subscriber',
                DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
               'plsql://P_MDMS_QUEUE_CB_PROCEDURE?PR=0',
                HEXTORAW('FF')
                )
             ),
          1
          );          

DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE (
    'ALL','UIMSMGR.MDMS_QUEUE',  'BAN_DEFAULT_M');
```

So now, when messages are posted to the queue, I run this query:

```
select DBA_QUEUES.NAME  , aq.*
from gv$aq aq,
dba_queues
where aq.qid  = dba_queues.qid
and
name like '%MDMS_QUEUE%'
```

And all the messages are sitting in the READY state.  When I query v$process, I see that the program, "QMNC" is running as per this [Oracle Troublshooting Doc](https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/oracle_support_master_note_for_aq_queue_monitor_process_qmon_doc_id_3056621).  I can manually de-queue the messages by calling DBMS_AQ.dequeue().  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, I Have opened an SR with oracle support,and they are not even sure what is going on...

Comment: Have you fixed this? I'm having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502535/oracle-advance-queue-dequeue-not-working

Comment: No, it would only happen on certain databases, but worked fine on others.  I opened an SR with oracle, and they basically gave up.

Comment: Can you specify the DB versions who had this problem and the ones you could make it work, please?

Comment: It was 11.2 - same version, just different instances.

Answer (score 0):

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077791/what-is-the-syntax-for-creating-a-queue-subscriber-in-pl-sql/26020268#26020268) for some aspects to be considered in oracle aq. Seems that some versions of the database have problems reported in metalink. Also try to recreate the objects if you have a working version before.