# Oracle Advance Queue - Dequeue not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-aq

I can't seem to find the solution to my problem, I've been stuck at this for hours.

I'm usings Oracle AQs:

```
       Dbms_Aqadm.Create_Queue_Table(Queue_Table        => 'ITEM_EVENT_QT',
                                    Queue_Payload_Type => 'ITEM_EVENT',
                                    Multiple_Consumers => TRUE);

       Dbms_Aqadm.Create_Queue(Queue_Name          => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                              Queue_Table         => 'ITEM_EVENT_QT',
                              Max_Retries         => 5,
                              Retry_Delay         => 0,
                              Retention_Time      => 432000, -- 5 DAYS
                              Dependency_Tracking => FALSE,
                              COMMENT             => 'Item Event Queue');
       -- START THE QUEUE
       Dbms_Aqadm.Start_Queue('ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE');
       -- GRANT QUEUE PRIVILEGES
       Dbms_Aqadm.Grant_Queue_Privilege(Privilege    => 'ALL',
                                       Queue_Name   => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                                       Grantee      => 'PUBLIC',
                                       Grant_Option => FALSE);
    END;
```

Here's one of my subscribers:

```
Dbms_Aqadm.Add_Subscriber(Queue_Name => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                            Subscriber => Sys.Aq$_Agent('ITEM_SUBSCRIBER_1',
                                                        NULL,
                                                        NULL),
                            rule   =>  'tab.user_data.header.thread_no = 1');

   Dbms_Aq.Register(Sys.Aq$_Reg_Info_List(Sys.Aq$_Reg_Info('ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE:ITEM_SUBSCRIBER_1',
                                                          Dbms_Aq.Namespace_Aq,
                                                          'plsql://ITEM_API.GET_QUEUE_FROM_QUEUE',
                                                          HEXTORAW('FF'))),1);
```

The subscriber registration:

Whenever a certain event occurs on my DB, I'm using a trigger to add "the event" to my AQ by calling the following procedure from my `ITEM_API` package:

```
  PROCEDURE ADD_EVENT_TO_QUEUE(I_EVENT       IN ITEM_EVENT,
                               O_STATUS_CODE OUT VARCHAR2,
                               O_ERROR_MSG   OUT VARCHAR2) IS

    ENQUEUE_OPTIONS    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
    MESSAGE_HANDLE     RAW(16);
    EVENT              ITEM_EVENT;
    HEADER_PROP        HEADER_PROPERTIES;
  BEGIN
    EVENT                              := I_EVENT;
    EVENT.SEQ_NO                       := ITEM_EVENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    ENQUEUE_OPTIONS.VISIBILITY         := DBMS_AQ.ON_COMMIT;
    ENQUEUE_OPTIONS.SEQUENCE_DEVIATION := NULL;
    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES.PRIORITY        := 1;
    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES.DELAY           := DBMS_AQ.NO_DELAY;
    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES.EXPIRATION      := DBMS_AQ.NEVER;
    HEADER_PROP                        := HEADER_PROPERTIES(1);
    EVENT.HEADER                       := HEADER_PROP;
    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(QUEUE_NAME         => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                    ENQUEUE_OPTIONS    => ENQUEUE_OPTIONS,
                    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES => MESSAGE_PROPERTIES,
                    PAYLOAD            => EVENT,
                    MSGID              => MESSAGE_HANDLE);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_HANDLER.LOG_ERROR(NULL,
                              EVENT.ITEM,
                              EVENT.SEQ_NO,
                              SQLCODE,
                              SQLERRM,
                              O_STATUS_CODE,
                              O_ERROR_MSG);
      RAISE;
  END ADD_EVENT_TO_QUEUE;
```

And it's working because when I check my AQ table, I can find "the event", however my dequeue method is not dequeing, as you can see in the image bellow, there's no `DEQ_TIME`.

Here's my dequeue method, also from my `ITEM_API` package:

```
  PROCEDURE GET_QUEUE_FROM_QUEUE(CONTEXT  RAW,
                                 REGINFO  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
                                 DESCR    SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
                                 PAYLOAD  RAW,
                                 PAYLOADL NUMBER) IS

    R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    R_MESSAGE_PROPERTIES DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
    V_MESSAGE_HANDLE     RAW(16);
    I_PAYLOAD            ITEM_EVENT;
    L_PROC_EVENT         BOOLEAN;
    O_TARGETS            CFG_EVENT_STAGE_TBL;
    O_ERROR_MSG          VARCHAR2(300);
    O_STATUS_CODE        VARCHAR2(100);
  BEGIN
    R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.MSGID         := DESCR.MSG_ID;
    R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.CONSUMER_NAME := DESCR.CONSUMER_NAME;
    R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.DEQUEUE_MODE  := DBMS_AQ.REMOVE;
    --R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.WAIT          := DBMS_AQ.NO_WAIT;
    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(QUEUE_NAME         => DESCR.QUEUE_NAME,
                    DEQUEUE_OPTIONS    => R_DEQUEUE_OPTIONS,
                    MESSAGE_PROPERTIES => R_MESSAGE_PROPERTIES,
                    PAYLOAD            => I_PAYLOAD,
                    MSGID              => V_MESSAGE_HANDLE);
    IF I_PAYLOAD IS NOT NULL THEN
      L_PROC_EVENT := PROCESS_EVENT(I_PAYLOAD,
                                    O_TARGETS,
                                    O_STATUS_CODE,
                                    O_ERROR_MSG);
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_HANDLER.LOG_ERROR(NULL,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              SQLCODE,
                              SQLERRM,
                              O_STATUS_CODE,
                              O_ERROR_MSG);
      RAISE;
  END GET_QUEUE_FROM_QUEUE;
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this? I think there might be a problem with my subscriber registration, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** I've just figured out that if I remove the subscribers and the register, and then re-add them, they'll dequeue all messages. Howerver if another event gets enqueued, it stays there indefinetly (or until I remove and add the subscribers again):

The record with state 0 and no `DEQ_TIME` is the new one.

Do I need a scheduler or something like that?

**EDIT:** I've added a scheduler propagation to my AQ:

```
DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION('ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE');
```

and even added the next_time field:

```
DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION('ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE', SYSDATE + 30/86400);
```

Still doesn't work. Any suggestions? I guess the AQ Notifications aren't working, and my callback procedure is never called. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I've removed my procedure from the package just for testing purposes, so my team mates can compile the ITEM_API package (I don't know if recompiling the package, may or may not have impacts on the dequeue process).
Still doesn't work.

Comment: My guess: commit the transaction in which you did the enqueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a code block and run the following:

```
DECLARE
  dequeue_options      DBMS_AQ.dequeue_options_t;
  message_properties   DBMS_AQ.message_properties_t;
  message_handle       RAW (16);
  I_PAYLOAD            ITEM_EVENT;
  no_messages exception;
  msg_content          VARCHAR2 (4000);
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (no_messages, -25228);
BEGIN
  dequeue_options.wait := DBMS_AQ.NO_WAIT;
  dequeue_options.consumer_name := 'ITEM_SUBSCRIBER_1';   
  dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;
LOOP    
 DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE (queue_name           => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                      dequeue_options      => dequeue_options,
                      message_properties   => message_properties,
                      payload              => I_PAYLOAD,
                      msgid                => message_handle
                     );
END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_messages
  THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No more messages left');
END;
```

Let me know what happens to your enqueued messages.

You should have a table where you're dequing the data.

Can you also try adding the enqueud table in the agent and then specify the agent to the dequeue table.

```
DECLARE
  aSubscriber sys.aq$_agent;
BEGIN 
  aSubscriber := sys.aq$_agent('ITEM_SUBSCRIBER_1',
                          'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE',
                          0);
  dbms_aqadm.add_subscriber
 ( queue_name     => 'ITEM_EVENT_QUEUE'
  ,subscriber     => aSubscriber);
END;
/
```

Comment: Sorry, just use your message type.

Comment: Didn't help, the enqueued messages stayed in the queue as before. You get +1 because of the work you had. Thanks. P.S.: I've edited my post, maybe it can help

Answer (score 1):

We faced a related problem (at least related to the title), we couldn't dequeue messages with a delay. The messages in the queue stayed the state "WAITING". And were not changed to "READY".

The Oracle AQ monitoring process that is responsable for changing the state from "WAITING" to "READY" (after the delay is expired) wasn't working properly.

For us a database restart fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but it was solved after changing these 2 DB parameters:

1. job_queue_processes (must be > than 0)
2. aq_tm_processes (autotuning)

Hope it helps.